# Is there an equivalent of host.docker.internal for Kubernetes cluster running as part of Windows Docker Desktop

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

Usecase:
I have a Docker desktop and kubernetes enabled within it. From the kubernetes node, I want to connect to a database running on my laptop without using my laptop's ip address.

I want to refer to the Windows Host machine from within Kuberntes Endpoint without using the dynamic IP of the host. In docker there is a special DNS name host.docker.internal that allows host machine endpoints to be connected. I am not able to specify this for the endpoint IP. Is there something equivalent in Kubernetes?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have not found the answer to it. I changed my approach to installing oracle within kubernetes using this - https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

Answer (score 5):

Use `host.docker.internal`.

I've tested on Mac, but it should work the same for Windows.

1. Spin up an alpine pod (deployment yaml [borrowed from rossbackp](https://github.com/infrabricks/kubernetes-standalone/blob/master/examples/alpine.yml)).

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: alpine
     namespace: default
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: alpine:3.2
       command:
         - /bin/sh
         - "-c"
         - "sleep 60m"
       imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
       name: alpine
     restartPolicy: Always
   ```

   ```bash
   kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml  # after saving the above file as deployment.yaml
   ```
2. Start a simple web server, on the host.

   ```bash
   mkdir /tmp/server
   cd /tmp/server
   echo "hi" > index.html
   python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
   ```
3. Access the web server from the alpine pod.

   ```bash
   kubectl exec -it alpine -- sh
   wget -O- host.docker.internal:8000
   ```

Comment: This wont work if you application need to connect to the database running on host during startup

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using telepresence, https://www.telepresence.io/

Comment: It does not, but I have changed my approach to using oracle within kubernetes - https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance